# (Español/PHP) mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Antes que nada, me gustaría comentarles que no encontré todavía solución y por eso recurro al foro, se que esta pregunta parece repetida, pero por este caso en particular estoy probando un trabajo practico para la facultad (soy principiante, estoy haciendo esto para rendir un final) que en **XAMPP no me genera ningún problema** y al probarlo en 000webhost me salta un error.

El index es así:

```
`<?php
//--------SESION PHP------//
session_start();
$varsesion = $_SESSION;
?>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The Data Ecosystem</title>
  <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--JQuery JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--p5 js - core -->
  <script src="js/p5.js"></script>
  <!--p5 libreria de sonido -->
  <script src="js/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <!--p5 - sketch de trabajo -->
  <!--<script src="sketch.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">The Data Ecosystem</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">¿Que es? <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!--------NAVBAR--------->
    <!-----INICIO DEL PHP---------->
    <?php
          //INCLUYE LA CONEXION
          include("conectarServer.php");
          //SI LA CONEXION ESTA NULA O VACIA MUESTRA EL HEADER QUE PIDE QUE INICIE SESION
        if(($varsesion==null) || ($varsesion='')){
          echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          <a href='registrarse.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Registrarse</button></a>
          <a href='iniciarSesion.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-dark'>Iniciar Sesión</button></a>
      </ul>";
          //SI EL USUARIO YA INICIO SESION, MUESTRA EL ADM. DE PERFILES O CERRAR SESION
        }
        else {
          echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          <a href='perfil.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Perfil</button></a>
          <a href='cerrarSesion.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-dark'>Cerrar Sesion</button></a>
      </ul>";
        }
        //SELECCIONAME EL CAMPO EDAD DE LA TABLA USUARIOS
        $solicitud = "SELECT edad FROM usuarios";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$solicitud);
        //LA VARIABLE FILAS ALMACENA LA CANT. DE CAMPOS SELECCIONADOS
        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if($filas > 0){
          for ($i = 0; $i < $filas; $i++){
            //COMO MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY SOLO LO HACE CON UNA SOLA FILA
            //VOY OCUPANDO CADA LUGAR DEL ARRAY CON LA EDADES
            $verconfig = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); //verconfig es una variable que almacena temporalmente los datos
            $arrayDatos[$i] = $verconfig['edad']; //siendo este el array que almacena los datos finales
          }
          //CREO UNA VARIABLE EDAD Y LA CONVIERTO A JSON
          $edad = json_encode($arrayDatos);
          //print_r($arrayDatos);
        }
        
    ?>`
```

Cabe aclarar las siguientes cosas:
*En PhpMyAdmin de XAMPP ya exporté en SQL los datos de la tabla y los importé en el PhpMyAdmin de 000webhost
*En el archivo conectarServer.php verifiqué todos los datos y entra bien
*Estoy usando la última version de PHP (7.4), también lo intente con 7.2

Comment: conectarServer.php trae $conn verdad? de ser así podrías incorporar el código de conectarServer.php please

Comment: Por supuesto @KevinDelva :
<?php
    //Datos para conectarse al server
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id15885026_julio";
    $password = "NoemiGloria1675!";
    $dbname = "usuarios_obra";
    
    // Crear conexion
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    // Chequeando conexión
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("La conexion ha fallado: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else{
    //echo "Conectado a la base de datos!<br>";
    }
    
    ?>

Comment: lo más probable es que la información que le asignas a `$username`, `$password` y `$dbname` no sean las mismas en 000webhost, debes usar el usuario y passwd que creaste en cpanel ya que la mayoría de los host dan nomenclatura a los datos

Comment: Hola @KevinDelva antes que nada muchas gracias por ayudarme a seguir con este tema
Puedo dar fé de que ese user y password son los del cpanel, los conseguí de ahí mismo (antes lo datos que tenía eran "root" en el user y "" en psswd), además corroboré de que funcione la conexión, es decir, descomenté la linea del "else" que dice Conectado a la base de datos! y entró correctamente por el echo. ¿Alguna sugerencia de que más podría llegar a ser?

Comment: Puedes capturar el error de mysql para saber que esta pasando, te dejo el [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) de como implementarlo. Por favor comparte el error en caso de que encuentres algo, para apoyarte mejor y que pueda ayudar a alguien mas.